# Como criar um arquivo ZIP no Shell?

Tags: shell-script, shell, arquivo-zip

Como faço para criar um arquivo ZIP no Shell com os arquivos da data de hoje? Os arquivos estão todos no mesmo diretório.

Comment: Já tentou alguma coisa? Conhece os comandos `zip`, `find` e `man`?

Comment: Eu estava usando o compress-archive

Comment: Mas estava com dificuldades na hora de pegar os arquivos com a data de hoje

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar alguma coisa parecida com:

find . -ctime -1 -iname "*.txt" -exec zip arquivos.zip {} \;

O find tem algumas opções interessantes para procurar arquivos baseados na data de criação, acesso e modificação. Dá uma olhadinha no man dele.